# Web Form User Control Render HTML

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I have 2 controls in ascx file.

1) `<input type="checkbox"  id='<%= ECA_AdditionalOffers[i].Value["text"] %>_x'/>`

2 )`<asp:Literal Text='<%= ECA_AdditionalOffers[i].Value["text"] %>' runat="server" />`

Everything is fine with checkbox. But literal control is not allowing me, to use '<%=' correctly. What can I do?

It just renders me this:

```
<div class="fleft for_dis" style="padding-top:2px;">

                       <input id="M:Vairuotojo ir keleivių draudimas <b>(+ 3 EUR)</b>_x" type="checkbox">
                        &lt;%= ECA_AdditionalOffers[i].Value["text"] %&gt;
                    </div>
```

Comment: `asp:Literal` is a server side control and you can't write this `<% %>` instead of that bind from code behind.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You are right. Server side controls can't be touched with this method.